# What does return 2 mean in C? And additional questions on bool and void. CS50 Pset 3 Plurality

Tags: c, cs50

Currently doing the CS50 Pset3 Plurality exercise and reviewing the code given. I'm wondering what does return 2 mean in the code.

Some additional questions -

Why is bool vote(string name); and void print_winner(void); not within the curly brackets of int main (int argc, string arg[])? I am unsure why it is written this way, I would like to understand the reasoning behind this.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    // Display winner of election
    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }

    }

    // TODO
    return false;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    int maxvote = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (maxvote < candidates[i].votes)
        {
            maxvote = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {

        if (candidates[i].votes == maxvote)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
    }

    // TODO
    return;
}
```

Comment: The return value of `main` is available to the program/person that runs the program. Each return value indicates a particular exit condition . By convention `0` means success and other values indicate application specific error conditions.

Comment: `return 2` means to return the value `2` from the function. I'd suggest you find a good C language tutorial; to learn the basics about the language this is basic information you'd learn from the topic on functions. Your other questions would be answered there as well in that same topic. If you're not familiar with those, you're not ready for the exercises you're attempting.

Comment: Along with any application there will be documentation for that app that details what each return value means. Take a look at the "Return value" section of any C manual page for examples of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return 2` in the `main()` function means that the program will exit with exit code 2, indicating an error (anything non-zero is generally considered an error). The program is set up as follows:

- exit code 0 indicates success (or it should, anyways. The program is missing `return 0` at the end of `main()`)
- exit code 1 indicates no arguments were specified
- exit code 2 indicates that candidate_count is greater than the maximum

Return codes have no meaning within the program. However, when the program is actually run, the parent process (often a shell, such as Bash) can interpret the return code to gather meaningful information about the process' status.

These

```
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);
```

are function declarations, which allow code written after them to call the functions with the given signatures. The definitions follow later in the code; in C, the function definition does not need to be in the same file as the declaration, as long as the function can be found at link-time.

Comment: Thanks! In this case, would writing return 1 in its place generate the same effect?

Also, why would one write return 2 instead of return 1?

Comment: They have different meanings outside of the program. If I were to run this program in the shell, I would know that if it returned error code 1, that meant I didn't specify enough arguments. If it returned 2, I would know that candidate_count is greater than the maximum. This is all about what you as the programmer want; there's no effect from a functionality perspective within the program.